How can I position a taichi GUI window on screen?
I have started to work with Python's Taichi package and I couldn't find how to position the GUI window.
A simple example:
import taichi as ti

gui = ti.GUI("Test", (640, 480))

while gui.running:
  if gui.get_event(ti.GUI.PRESS):
    gui.running = False
  # ... 
  gui.show()

Each time I run this, the window is placed at different locations. I would like to have a fixed location, mainly for automatic image screenshots and animation recordings in which the window needs to be grabbed.
Is there a way to fix the location of the window?

I have found a solution, which useds another method of taichi window creation. This method accepts window positioning. Here's a corresponding example:
import taichi as ti

window = ti.ui.Window("Test", (640,480), pos=(0,0))
while window.running:
  if window.get_event(ti.ui.PRESS):
    window.running = False
  # ...
  window.show()

